# Отсортировать массив java

Tags: java, сортировка

Не могу отсортировать массив (скорее всего нужен по убыванию). В задании стоит задача вывести двух самых высоких людей, то есть найти два максимальных числа (в файле txt у меня записаны имена и рост каждого человека). Помогите пожалуйста, я уже больше месяца мучаюсь! Все, что мне говорят - "отсортируй массив", "используй метод sort" и все в таком роде. Я это всё прекрасно понимаю, но у меня не получается. Может кто-то написать саму сортировку именно для моей программы? Пожалуйста!!! (Сортировка нужна в конце программы, я комментарием отметила место)

```
package lab22; 
//Определить двух высоких студентов
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class ex1 { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    ArrayList <Svedenia> arr = new ArrayList <Svedenia> (); 
    BufferedReader in = null; 
    try { 
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Z:\\Документы\\Новая папка\\in.txt"));
        String s; 
        int n = 0; 
        System.out.println("______________________"); 
        while((s = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            int p = s.indexOf(","); 
            Svedenia sved = new Svedenia(s.substring(0, p), Double.parseDouble(s.substring(p+1))); 
            arr.add(sved); 

            System.out.printf("|%10s%10.2f|\n", 
                    arr.get(n).getName(), 
                    arr.get(n).getResult()); 
            n++;
        } 
    }
    finally { 
        in.close(); 
    }       
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Z:\\Документы\\Новая папка\\out.txt"); 

    System.out.println("Фамилия: "); 
    double max=0,max2=0;
    int n = 0;

//СОРТИРОВКА:     

    Collections.sort(arr, new  Comparator<Svedenia>(){
        public int compare(Svedenia o1, Svedenia o2) {
            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }});
    System.out.println(o1); 
    System.out.println(o2); 

    for(Svedenia entry:arr){
        if ((entry.getResult()==max)||(entry.getResult()==max2)){
            System.out.println(entry.getResult() + ", " + entry.getName()); 
            out.write(entry.getResult() + ", " + entry.getName() + "\r\n"); 
        }
    }
    out.close(); 
    } 
}
```

### И вторая программа (Сведения):

```
package lab22; 

public class Svedenia { 

    private String name; 
    private double result;

    public Svedenia(String n, double r) { 
        name = n; 
        result = r; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return name; 
    } 

    public double getResult() { 
        return result; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: зачем вы нам весь код скинули?

Comment: для начала в вашей "программе" Сведения переопределите метод compareTo
А дальше, что - то типо такого: arr= arr.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(arr, new  Comparator<Svedenia>(){
    public int compare(Svedenia o1, Svedenia o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
}});
```

У вас в компараторе объект приводится к строке - вызывается метод `toString`, который не переопределен в классе `Svedenia`.
Чтобы компаратор работал правильно, нужно либо переопределить метод `toString`, например так:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return name + " " + result;
}
```

либо, этот вариант более правильный, реализовать в классе `Svedenia` интерфейс `Comparable` и, соответственно, написать метод `compareTo`, например так (тогда не надо будет вызывать `toString`):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Svedenia s){
    int cmp = name.compareTo(s.getName());
    if(cmp == 0) cmp = Double.compare(result, s.getResult());
    return cmp;
}
```

и написать так:

```
Collections.sort(arr, new  Comparator<Svedenia>(){
    public int compare(Svedenia o1, Svedenia o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала в вашей "программе" Сведения переопределите метод `compareTo`
А дальше, что - то типо такого:

```
arr= arr.stream()
        .sorted((f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f2, f1))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayL‌​ist::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Определить двух высоких студентов
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class ex1 { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    ArrayList <Svedenia> arr = new ArrayList <> (); 
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Z:\\Документы\\Новая папка\\in.txt"))) {
        String s; 
        int n = 0; 
        System.out.println("______________________"); 
        while((s = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            int p = s.indexOf(","); 
            Svedenia sved = new Svedenia(s.substring(0, p), Double.parseDouble(s.substring(p+1))); 
            arr.add(sved); 

            System.out.printf("|%10s%10.2f|\n", 
                    arr.get(n).getName(), 
                    arr.get(n).getResult()); 
            n++;
        } 
    }

    Collections.sort(arr, (Svedenia o1, Svedenia o2) -> o2.getResult().compareTo(o1.getResult()));
    System.out.println(arr.get(0));
    System.out.println(arr.get(1));

    } 
}

class Svedenia { 

    private final String NAME; 
    private final Double RESULT;

    public Svedenia(String name, Double result) { 
        this.NAME = name; 
        this.RESULT = result; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return NAME; 
    } 

    public Double getResult() { 
        return RESULT; 
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return NAME + ", " + RESULT;
    }

}
```

Comment: Получите двух самых высоких первым и вторым элементов вашей коллекции. Этот код выведет результат в консоль, но вы можете сохранить в файл, разницы нет.

Comment: Если код непонятный, то задавайте вопросы, а то толку от написанного за вас кода никакого.